# C#: byte array in xml CData

Tags: c#, xml, arrays, cdata, abcpdf

I have a WCF service that is returning a block of xml.  One element is a CData[] section.  My application reads an HTML file out of the database and converts it to a PDF byte[] array using ABCPDF.  Then in my XmlWriter Im adding the bytes to the CData section.

The problem is the resulting xml looks like this:

```
<![CDATA[System.Byte[]]]>
```

How can I get the string of bytes into the CData section?  I've tried things like:

```
string str;
ASCIIEncoding enc = new ASCIIEncoding();
str = enc.GetString(theData);
```

and

```
Convert.ToBase64String(theData);
```

Im stuck!!  Any help would be great, thank you!

Comment: What are you getting in your output when you use Convert.ToBase64String?  That's probably the best way to do it (using ASCIIEncoding.GetString only works if the bytes represent a valid ASCII string).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `Convert.ToBase64String(data)` is *definitely* the way to go here if you've got control of both ends. You don't want to be sending down "raw" bytes and pretending they're valid text data. Use `Convert.FromBase64String(text)` at the other side.

I'm slightly surprised that WCF isn't handling this for you automatically though. I can't say I've used it myself (Marc Gravell might pop in - he's got a lot of experience with it, I believe) but I'd expect it to just expose byte arrays. Why are you involved at the level of the XML?

Comment: Specifically many control characters are not allowed in XML documents, including nul (0).

Comment: Convert.ToBase64String() works now, I was still returning the byte array in my method.  Grrrr!!!  Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say exactly where your problem's happening - a more complete code example might help. But from what you show as getting serialized - it looks an awful lot like `ToString()` is being called on your `byte[]`.

You should look into using `Convert.ToBase64String()` if you are trying to send binary data over the wire. If you are not in control of the receiving format, you need to look into what encoding it requires.